# Android date picker to select a single day or a range of dates

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

Does anyone know a date picker to select a single day or a range of dates in Android? The material components date picker allows you to select either a date or a date range, but both options are not implemented in the same picker. I want to give the user the option to select a day or a date range. It depends on them. One with an appearance as similar as possible to that provided by material components would be appreciated.